# print unordered_map<std::string, std::list<std::string>

Tags: boost, unordered-map

I have unordered_map. which has client and their associated users in std::list.
I can print my client, but don't know how to print its userslist.

```
mapType clientUserMap;

clientUserMap.insert (mapType::value_type("C1", std::list<std::string> (userlist)));

boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >
         ::const_iterator it = clientUserMap.find("C1");

 std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a list, so iterate through the list and print.. e.g.

```
for(std::list<std::string>::const_iterator l_it = begin(it->second); l_it != end(it->second); ++l_it)
  std::cout << *l_it << std::endl;
```

Of course there are many more fancy ways of doing this...

Comment: When I tried I got the following errors

 warning: 'auto' will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it
 error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'l_it' with no type
 error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
 error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
 error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'

Comment: @user1841046, I am using a keyword from c++11, please change it to match the iterator type of the list...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is iterate over the list:

```
std::list<string> const &users = it->second;
std::for_each(users.begin(), users.end(), [](string const& user){std::cout << user << std::endl;}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you already using boost, you could also use BOOST_FOREACH to iterate over the user list.
The code would then look like this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
...

boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >
  ::const_iterator it = clientUserMap.find("C1");

std::cout << it->first << std::endl;

BOOST_FOREACH( std::string user, it->second )
{
   std::cout << user << endl;
}
```